# выдает ошибку local variable 'randc' referenced before assignment dicsord.py

Tags: python

у меня ошибки
вот код

````
async def Mishka(ctx):
    global x
    r = (random.randint(1,1000))
    if r <= 799>800:
        randc = (random.choice(rand2))
    elif r >= 801<950:
        randc = (random.choice(rand1))
    elif r >= 951<1000:
        randc = (random.choice(rand3))
    await ctx.send(randc) ```
````

Comment: почитайте по синтаксис python

Answer (score 0):

Условие `x < y < z` эквивалентно условию `x < y and y < z`. Какой именно знак сравнения там не важно, суть в том,  как это раскладываестся на два условия, правило одинаковое. Поэтому первое ваше условие вообще никогда не выполняется, а в оставшихся правая часть выполняется всегда. В целом похоже у вас условия не сработали и переменной ничего не присвоилось до отсылки.

Comment: а это можно как то исправить? чтобы они сразу два активровались или похоже?

Comment: спасибо вам!!!!

Comment: Ну вы просто подумайте, какую логику вы хотите реализовать.